# how to use groupby() + cumsum() + last()

Tags: python, pandas

How to make this groupby() cumsum() show only the `last` cumsum() by its groupby(), in this new column?

`df_dea['profit_usd'] = df_dea.groupby('key_br_acc_posid')['notional_usd'].cumsum()`

if I insert a `.last()` at the end of this code I get an error:

`TypeError: last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`

Comment: you want to show only the last cumsum in the last row or the last cumsum in all rows?

Comment: last cumsum for each grouping, just in the last row

Comment: solved with one more line code with .tail(1)